# Can bootchart be configured to save only current log?

Tags: bootchart

I found over a gigabyte of files in var/log/bootchart. I don't want any but the most recent file to be saved. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably set a cron script to do that.

I assume (in this answer) the files are named `bootchart.log.1` and so on.

Run `crontab -e` as the root user, select your editor and add into the end of the file:

`@reboot /bin/sleep 60 && /bin/rm /var/log/bootchart/bootchart.log.*`

Let's break it down

`@reboot` Tells cron to run on reboot.
`/bin/sleep` The command CRON runs. This is the x of the `&&` statement. 
`60` The delay for `sleep`, in seconds.
`&&` Fancy Linux for "do y after x is done" as in `x && y`
`/bin/rm` The y of the `&&` statement. It is the "delete" command of Linux.
`/var/log/bootchart/bootchart.log.*` The file to delete for `rm`. It says "delete all files beginning with `bootchart.log.` (note the dot at the end) in the folder `/var/log/bootchart/`

About the `bootchart.log.*`, a file named `bootchart.log.1` or `bootchart.log.bak` or`bootchart.log.old` or `bootchart.log.chicken` will be deleted, but `bootchart.log` itself will not.